# Page gets reloaded in ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm trying to build a subscribe form. 
The problem is that the page gets redirected, and the data doesn't get entered into db,
page gets redirected to

```
http://localhost/xampp/MY/SUB_FOLDERS/includes/parse.php?subscriber=sid%40patel&subscribe=subscribe
```

HTML CODE

```
        <div id="subsc">
            <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" action="includes/parse.php" mathod="post">
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="email" placeholder="Email" class="form-control" name="subs" id="subs" required="required">
              </div>
              <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="subscribe" id="subscribe" value="subscribe">
            </form>
          </div>
```

Ajax code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

   $("#subscribe").click(function(){
    username=$("#subs").val();


         $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "includes/parse.php",
            //data:dataString,
            success: function(html){

        if(html=='true')
              {
                $("#subsc").fadeOut("normal");

                $("#subsc").html("Thank you for subscriping!");

              }
              else
              {
                    $("#subsc").html("Error in subscribing");
              }
            },

        });
         return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

PHP script for inserting data to database:

```
<?php include("connect.php");


if (@$_POST['subs']) {
 $subscriber = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($_POST['subs']));

 $sendmessage = mysql_query("INSERT INTO subscriber VALUES('','$subscriber',now())");
 echo 'true';

}

?>
```

PS: Name of rows in  subscriber id, email, datetime

Comment: Aside: You shouldn't bind a form submit to the click event of an input:submit button - there is more than one way to submit a form, e.g. pressing enter in an input:text field. Please use `$('#theformid').on('submit', function(){...});`

Answer (score 0):

Add an id on your form:

```
<form id="myform" class="navbar-form navbar-right" action="includes/parse.php" method="post">
```

Change your Javascript to:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

   $("#myform").submit(function(event){
    username=$("#subs").val();


         $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "includes/parse.php",
            //data:dataString,
            success: function(html){

        if(html=='true')
              {
                $("#subsc").fadeOut("normal");

                $("#subsc").html("Thank you for subscriping!");

              }
              else
              {
                    $("#subsc").html("Error in subscribing");
              }
            },

        });
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
</script>
```

This will prevent the default action of the form to submit the data and the apparent redirect. Also by handling the form's submit event you also handle the situation where the form may be submitted by other means.

Comment: It stops from geting redirected but only when, i change subscribe element from submit to button. However it doesn't solve the problem, the page stays as it is and nothing happens.
PS: data doesn't get entered to db

Comment: Sorry but it doesn't. If i'm giving it an id shouldn't it be #myform?
problem remains the same after i did changes as you said, page gets redirected

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing to do would be changing the type of your `#subscribe` element to `button` instead of `submit`.

```
    <div id="subsc">
        <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" id="SubsForm">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="email" placeholder="Email" class="form-control" name="subscriber" id="subs" required="required">
          </div>
          <input type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="subscribe" value="subscribe">
        </form>
      </div>
```

And JavaScript -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

   $("#subscribe").click(function(){  
         $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "includes/parse.php",
            data:$('#SubsForm').serialize(),
            success: function(html){
              if (html=='true') {
                     $("#subsc").fadeOut("normal");
                     $("#subsc").html("Thank you for subscriping!");
              } else {
                     $("#subsc").html("Error in subscribing");
              }
          },
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

More about $().serialize can be found here - http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

> The .serialize() method creates a text string in standard URL-encoded
>   notation. It can act on a jQuery object that has selected individual
>   form controls....

Comment: yes, it doesn't get redirected, but then nothing happens whatsoever

Comment: Well, yes. Because no data was being sent. Updated the answer. Try it.

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is one simpler approach here using your existing code itself...Instead of these lines:
$("#subscribe").click(function(){
    username=$("#subs").val();

Use these lines:
$("#subscribe").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
.   e.stopPropagation();
    username=$("#subs").val();

This should stop the form post back even for submit button.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Did you checked your page in browser with JavaScript console enabled? My guess, there should be some us error just before the page getting redirected. Or may be you should be also bind this function to form's submit event.

Answer (score 0):

First bind your subscribe button to a click event and Remove attribute action="includes/parse.php"

```
<input type="button" class="btn btn-success" name="subscribe" id="subscribe" value="subscribe">

jQuery('#subscribe').click(function(){
    jQuery.ajax({
        url:'YOUR URL',
        type:'POST',
        data:'subsribe=true&email='+jQuery('#subs').val(),
        success:function(data){
            if(data == 'true')
            {
              //enter code here
              window.location.reload(true);
            }else{
              //enter code here
              alert(data);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

SERVER SIDE

```
  /* AJAX check  */
    if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) &&strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
            if(isset($_POST)){
    $subscriber = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($_POST['subscriber']));
    $query = "INSERT INTO subscribers('email','timestamp') VALUES('$subscriber',NOW())";
     $sendmessage = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
     echo 'true';
            }
    }
```

Comment: sry but it doesn't work, page doesn't get redirected but, noting gets added to db and no changes are made to html...

Comment: PS: the page does get refreshed

Comment: Notice you do not have a column defined in your query